# Which thread(s) call `onCreateLoader()` and `onLoadFinished()`?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-cursorloader

I am implementing `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` in order to access my app's database and populate a `ListView`. Which threads will call my `onCreateLoader()` and `onLoadFinished()`? Are they called on the UI thread or the `CursorLoader`'s thread? The documentation for [LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) is mute on this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loader callback are called on the thread from which initloader method is called. In general it will be main thread.

Comment: Where is this documented? A link will help strengthen your answer.

Comment: I agree it is not documented but you can very well log the thread id in the loader callback methods and verify.

Comment: That's a good idea. I considered setting a breakpoint in the debugger as well.

Comment: Well, if you execute the method on a different thread than the main, you will get an exception saying: "initLoader must be called on the main thread".